# iOS WebRTC RTCMediaStreamTrack mute unmute remote audio track

Tags: ios, webrtc, webrtc-ios

I'm using the [latest](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/2/c/6/GoogleWebRTC/1.1.29400/GoogleWebRTC.podspec.json) native iOS GoogleWebRTC pod version 1.1.29400

I'm attempting to disable/enable the audio track on demand as specified in the WebRTC spec [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/enabled). In objective c, it is my understanding we call the `isEnabled` setter:

```c
RTCMediaStreamTrack *track = self.localTracks[trackId];
track.isEnabled = YES/NO;
```

In my app on iOS 13.1.3, this has no effect on the remote audio stream. It continues to play.

This is my understanding based on multiple examples:

- [Flutter WebRTC plugin](https://github.com/cloudwebrtc/flutter-webrtc/blob/master/ios/Classes/FlutterWebRTCPlugin.m#L294)
- [React Native WebRTC plugin](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc/blob/453c2de642c0cdf5719d67cfbd20af743e9ce147/ios/RCTWebRTC/WebRTCModule%2BRTCMediaStream.m#L216)
- [recent WebRTC example app](https://github.com/stasel/WebRTC-iOS/blob/master/WebRTC-Demo-App/Sources/Services/WebRTCClient.swift#L290)

I cannot find anywhere in [the official WebRTC iOS example](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/master/examples/objc/AppRTCMobile/) where they call `isEnabled` on a `RTCMediaStreamTrack`.

But, I do see them call `RTCAudioSession.isAudioEnabled` from the view controller, [here](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/master/examples/objc/AppRTCMobile/ios/ARDMainViewController.m#167). But, when I built that app and messed around with the `RTCAudioSession`, setting `isAudioEnabled` to false muted both the microphone input and speaker output. I only want to disable the speaker output while keeping the mic hot.

Any guidance or tips would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

In the [WebRTC M80 Release Notes](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/Ozvbd0p7Q1Y) they state they are going to be deprecating the mobile libraries.

To stay up to date with the latest bugfixes and features for the native mobile libraries (iOS and Android), we need to [build from source](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/master/docs/native-code/ios/index.md).

After I built the AppRTCMobile example app using `WebRTC.framework` built from source, I made a few changes and verified I was able to mute the remote audio track on demand.

In `ARDAppClient.h` I add a **strong** pointer reference for the remote `RTCMediaStream` and a method header for toggling the stream mute:

```c
@property(nonatomic, strong) RTCMediaStream *remoteAudioStream;
// ...
- (void)setRemoteAudioEnabled:(BOOL)enabled;
```

In `ARDAppClient.m` in the `RTCPeerConnectionDelegate` section, I listen to the `didAddStream` delegate and save a reference to the remote stream:

```c
- (void)peerConnection:(RTCPeerConnection *)peerConnection
          didAddStream:(RTCMediaStream *)stream {
  RTCLog(@"Stream with %lu video tracks and %lu audio tracks was added.",
         (unsigned long)stream.videoTracks.count,
         (unsigned long)stream.audioTracks.count);
  _remoteAudioStream = stream;
}
```

In `ARDAppClient.m` I also add a function to mute/unmute the stream we now have a reference to:

```c
- (void)setRemoteAudioEnabled:(BOOL)enabled {
  if (_state == kARDAppClientStateDisconnected) {
    return;
  }
  RTCLog(@"Setting remote stream to be %s", enabled ? "Enabled" : "Not Enabled");
  RTCLog(@"Number of remote audio tracks = %lu", (unsigned long)_remoteAudioStream.audioTracks.count);
  if (_remoteAudioStream.audioTracks.count == 0) {
    RTCLog(@"ERROR no audio tracks to disable!");
    return;
  }
  _remoteAudioTrack = _remoteAudioStream.audioTracks[0];
  [_remoteAudioTrack setIsEnabled:enabled];
}
```

Finally, in `ARDVideoCallViewController.m` I override the switch-camera button to toggle the remote audio track mute:

```c
- (void)videoCallViewDidSwitchCamera:(ARDVideoCallView *)view {
  // [_captureController switchCamera];
  self.audioEnabled = !self.audioEnabled;
  [_client setRemoteAudioEnabled:self.audioEnabled];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Works with the current GoogleWebRTC. Mutes / unmutes local mic and remote stream respectively:

```
func setMic(enabled: Bool) {
    for sender in peerConnection.senders {
        if sender.track?.kind == "audio" {
            sender.track?.isEnabled = enabled
        }
    }
}

func setRemoteTrack(enabled: Bool) {
    for receiver in peerConnection.receivers {
        if receiver.track?.kind == "audio" {
            receiver.track?.isEnabled = enabled
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem in Android.
Since Webrtc SDK for iOS and Android pretty similar you can use `AudioTrack.setVolume(0.0)` to mute and `AudioTrack.setVolume({value more than zero})` to unmute remote audio track.
But `isEnabled` property is not muting/unmuting for some reason.